# Pandas Error can only use .str accessor with string

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code,

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir('path\to\input\file')

xl_file = pd.ExcelFile('newcustomers.xlsx')
df = xl_file.parse('Customers Export 1', index_col='Domain', na_values=['NA'])

df = df[(df["Customer phone"].str.startswith("+1")) & (df["Customer phone"].str.len() == 13)]

print
print "now changing to final CSV output directory"
print

os.chdir('path\to\output\directory')

print "Current working dir : %s" % os.getcwd()

df.to_csv('newcustomers.csv')
```

Basically the column has phone numbers, and I am using this to remove incomplete numbers/blank entries, and phone numbers that don't start with +1. (the US/CA country dial code). It worked great for a week, but then I started getting this error. And I have not updated python or pandas in between.

```
raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string "
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

I am using anaconda on windows 8.1 the versions are as follows:

```
conda update conda
    conda 3.18.8 py27_0 defaults
conda update anaconda
    anaconda 2.4.0 np110py27_0 <unknown>
conda update pandas
    pandas 0.17.1 np110py27_0 defaults
```

Nothing has changed between all last week up to Sunday when the code worked, then yesterday without any updates, or changes to the input file or anything it starts getting mad at me :/

EDIT:
Adding df.head(2) per @WoodChopper request

```
Domain        Customer Name    Customer phone
example.com   John Doe         44.xxxxxx
google.com    Jane Doe         1.xxxxxx
```

In the original XLSX file that it is opening it does list the entire phone number with the '+' sign. But that is all that returns to CMD when I use:

```
print df.head(2)
```

And that is just doing the xl_file variable, the df variable, and then print the above statement. I am blocking out with # the

```
df = df[(df["Registrant phone"].str.startswith("+1")) & (df["Registrant phone"].str.len() == 13)]
```

EDIT x2

Just to clarify, this is the code as of now

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir('path\to\input\file')

df = pd.read_excel('newcustomers.xlsx', sheetname = 'Customers Export 1')

#xl_file = pd.ExcelFile('newcustomers.xlsx')
#df = xl_file.parse('Customers Export 1', index_col='Domain', na_values=['NA'], convert_float=False)
#df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)

#print df.head(2)
#print (df["Registrant phone"])
df = df[(df["Registrant phone"].str.startswith("+1")) & (df["Registrant phone"].str.len() == 13)]

print
print "now changing to final CSV output directory"
print

os.chdir('path\to\output\directory')

print "Current working dir : %s" % os.getcwd()

df.to_csv('newcustomers.csv')
```

Still returns all the same results. Just to make sure we're not chasing down the wrong rabbit, [Here is the exact error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVxBr.png)(imgur).

Could this be something outside the code? Pandas, conda, and anaconda are up to date. Is there another library that Pandas is dependent on that could have gone out of date (which wouldn't entirely make sense since everything worked one day and the next it didn't)?

Comment: .. did you add `print(df["Customer phone"])` before the line which is failing to work to see how pandas has interpreted that column?  Probably it's taking them as ints or floats instead.  (PS: these days `read_excel` is more idiomatic than using `ExcelFile` directly.)

Comment: @DSM Just tried that, it printed out the index column with the associated phones. Then at the bottom it says "Name: Customer Phone, dtype: float64"

Answer (score 1):

Basically phone number are parsed as `float`, but for your code to work it needs to be `string`.

Make convert_float as false:

```
df = xl_file.parse('Customers Export 1', index_col='Domain',
                                 na_values=['NA'], convert_float=False)
```

Update

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheetname = 'sheet 1')
```

Comment: Just tried that and it still gave me the same error. Just for kicks and giggles I also tried setting convert_float to True and it kicks out the same error. And tying in what @DSM told me to try to do, I did "print (df.....) and it still says "dtype: float 64" when convert_float is set to False.

Comment: added it as an edit in the original question so it would format nicer.

Comment: So it might be conversion issue. Check out `read_excel` works or not?

Comment: added another edit. As a side note, I HIGHLY appreciate your help! I am trying other stuff, but my programming knowledge is still young. This is my first real project outside of Codecademy and another MySQL uploader I made. :)